# How to connect to docker mysql container from Sequel Pro

Tags: mysql, docker

I have spent almost 2 weeks googling this and trying out tons of different solutions out there, but none of them seem to work for me.

I'm using Docker for Mac (there's a whale icon in my toolbar).

I'm using this command to create mysql container:

```
docker container run -d -p 3306:3306 --name=database -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root -e MYSQL_USER=local -e MYSQL_PASSWORD=local_password -v ~/.databases/mysql:/var/lib/mysql mysql
```

Here's the output of `docker container logs database`

```
2018-10-02T10:45:37.234437Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011070] [Server] 'Disabling symbolic links using --skip-symbolic-links (or equivalent) is the default. Consider not using this option as it' is deprecated
and will be removed in a future release.
2018-10-02T10:45:37.235186Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.12) starting as process 1
mbind: Operation not permitted
mbind: Operation not permitted
mbind: Operation not permitted
mbind: Operation not permitted
2018-10-02T10:45:37.927574Z 0 [System] [MY-010229] [Server] Starting crash recovery...
2018-10-02T10:45:37.927670Z 0 [System] [MY-010232] [Server] Crash recovery finished.
2018-10-02T10:45:38.012828Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2018-10-02T10:45:38.022161Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011810] [Server] Insecure configuration for --pid-file: Location '/var/run/mysqld' in the path is accessible to all OS users. Consider choosing a different
 directory.
2018-10-02T10:45:38.034910Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010315] [Server] 'user' entry 'mysql.infoschema@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
2018-10-02T10:45:38.034958Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010315] [Server] 'user' entry 'mysql.session@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
2018-10-02T10:45:38.034976Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010315] [Server] 'user' entry 'mysql.sys@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
2018-10-02T10:45:38.034988Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010315] [Server] 'user' entry 'root@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
2018-10-02T10:45:38.035012Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010323] [Server] 'db' entry 'performance_schema mysql.session@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.2018-10-02T10:45:38.035036Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010323] [Server] 'db' entry 'sys mysql.sys@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
2018-10-02T10:45:38.035053Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010311] [Server] 'proxies_priv' entry '@ root@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
2018-10-02T10:45:38.041121Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010330] [Server] 'tables_priv' entry 'user mysql.session@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
2018-10-02T10:45:38.041159Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010330] [Server] 'tables_priv' entry 'sys_config mysql.sys@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
2018-10-02T10:45:38.048971Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.12'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server - GPL
```

And I'm trying to connect to this container from Sequel Pro using the following settings:

```
Host: 127.0.0.1
Username: local
Password: local_password
```

And I'm getting the following error:

```
Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1, or the request timed out.

Be sure that the address is correct and that you have the necessary privileges, or try increasing the connection timeout (currently 10 seconds).

MySQL said: Authentication plugin 'caching_sha2_password' cannot be loaded: dlopen(/usr/local/lib/plugin/caching_sha2_password.so, 2): image not found
```

Comment: "I have spent almost 2 weeks googling this and trying out tons of different solutions out there, but none of them seem to work for me." Includes those in the question please

Answer (score 2):

Anyone else having this problem, it turns out that this happens because of the latest (8+) version of `mysql`. 5.7 version works fine.

Comment: Same thing. Switched to version 5 and it works. I have checked that MYSQL_USER and MYSQL_PASSWORD is not creating the user in the database. That is why you cannot connect to it outside of the docker container.

Comment: How do i do that?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to change the host-port to e.g. 33306 instead of 3306?

`docker container run -d -p 33306:3306 --name=database -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root -e MYSQL_USER=local -e MYSQL_PASSWORD=local_password -v ~/.databases/mysql:/var/lib/mysql mysql`

What else you can try, is going into the container and verify whether the MySQL engine is working from there.
You can do that by executing the following commands:

`docker exec -ti database bash
 mysql -p`

Comment: Hi @Mikki. I tried that as well and it's the same error. I can connect to the container interactively without a problem. I can add / remove users, manipulate the database and etc.

Answer (score 0):

here's what you could try if you're still looking for the solution. 
You might need to provide access to your user from all sources using the following.
`grant all privileges on *.* to 'root'@'%' identified by ‘’;`
flush privileges;